# facebook api FB.api("page_id/ratings?access_token not getting reviewer object in response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using following api for getting the ratting and a user comments for a page.

```
FB.api("/page_id/ratings?access_token="+access_token+"&limit=10&fields=reviewer{id,name,picture.width(120).height(120)},created_time,rating,recommendation_type,review_text,open_graph_story{id}",
```

but in response I just receive the review comments not a reviewer phone and its details.

Please suggest

Comment: "reviewer phone" ... so you want to get the PHONE of a reviewer? did i understand that correctly? just to be sure what you want to achieve. if that is really the case, what would you do with the phone? do you want to call him because he left a bad review? :)

Comment: No, I just  want the reviewer name, picture and rattings but currently I just getting review text i.e. comment text.  So that I can show the reviews on my site http://prntscr.com/p4louk

Comment: i would not put a reviewers name on some external website if he did not specifically agree to it, to be honest...i assume you don't get that data for a good reason.

Comment: I am using this api to get the reviews of business page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/recommendation/

but for the some reason I am not getting reviewer object in response

Comment: i know. still, i would not want my review (with my name!) to show up elsewhere without my explicit consent, just because i gave a rating on facebook.com. think about it.

Comment: ok. I getting your concern. but I am getting for all users with just rattings text not the user image and name. this should not happen for all users. I have tried at laest for 10-15 accounts. but for all this issue getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199310/discussion-between-somnath-rokade-and-luschn).